# Синтаксическая ошибка при изменении длины колонки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я новичок и вопрос очень простой, не судите строго. Дело в том, что когда я пытаюсь изменить длину колонки таблицы, я получаю **ERROR: syntax error at or near "MODIFY"**. В чем может быть причина?

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE movies MODIFY
  title VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу свой вариант, так как ответ tCode у меня не взлетел:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE movies ALTER COLUMN
  title TYPE VARCHAR(10);
```

И [ссылка](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html) на документацию. В postgre немного иначе это делается.

Comment: Теперь работает, благодарю.

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko В комментариях к удаленному ответу вы посетовали, что вариант не работающего запроса был приведен в книге. Не стоит винить книгу, дело в том, что в postgre модификация типа колонки делается иначе. Ваш же запрос прекрасно выполнится на MySql 5.6 например. Так что не спишите выкидывать книгу. :)